# List of pointers c++ opencv attrubuts change unexpectly

Tags: list, pointers

I want to save a list of point resulting of tracking an object in opencv

I utilise this list

```
list<list<OrganismPosition*>> trackList;
```

I insert a list and en element:

```
list<OrganismPosition*> sublist;
trackList.push_back(sublist);
list<list<OrganismPosition*>>::iterator itList=trackList.end();
itList--;
OrganismPosition* pos=new OrganismPosition();
//in this method I create a new point 
pos->setCenter(&box.center);//Here the point pos->center is (640,550)
itList->push_front(pos);//Error here the point pos->center has value (-103412,-102342)
```

The error is that when I add the object in the list the value of the attribuite "center" change with random value. What can be the problem and how resolve this? I have read that the list call the copy-constructor of the class so I have implemented this to copy the right value of attributes but still not working. I very appreciate any help. Thanks

My class OrganismPosition:

```
class OrganismPosition
{
    CvPoint2D32f* center;//center point of organisme tracked
    CvPoint2D32f* head;//head point of organisme tracked
    CvPoint2D32f* queue;//first point of organisme tracked
    CvPoint2D32f* skel1;//second point of organisme tracked
    CvPoint2D32f* skel2;//third point of organisme tracked
    CvPoint2D32f* skel3;//fourth point of organisme tracked
    CvPoint2D32f* skel4;//fiveth point of organisme tracked

public:
    OrganismPosition(void);
    ~OrganismPosition(void);
    OrganismPosition( const OrganismPosition& other );
    void setCenter(CvPoint2D32f* center);
    CvPoint2D32f* getCenter();
    void setHead(CvPoint2D32f* head);
    CvPoint2D32f* getHead();
    void setQueue(CvPoint2D32f* queue);
    CvPoint2D32f* getQueue();
    void setSkel(CvPoint2D32f* skel1,
                 CvPoint2D32f* skel2,
                 CvPoint2D32f* skel3,
                 CvPoint2D32f* skel4);
    void getSkel(CvPoint2D32f* skel1,
                 CvPoint2D32f* skel2,
                 CvPoint2D32f* skel3,
                 CvPoint2D32f* skel4);
};
```

Class OrganismPosition.cpp:

```
OrganismPosition::OrganismPosition(void)
{
}


OrganismPosition::~OrganismPosition(void)
{
}
OrganismPosition::OrganismPosition( const OrganismPosition& other )
  {
      OrganismPosition::center->x=other.center->x;
      OrganismPosition::center->y=other.center->y;
      OrganismPosition::head->x=other.head->x;
      OrganismPosition::head->y=other.head->y;


}


    void OrganismPosition::setCenter(CvPoint2D32f* center){
        CvPoint2D32f newcenter=cvPoint2D32f(center->x,center->y);
        this->center=&newcenter;
    }
    CvPoint2D32f* OrganismPosition::getCenter(){
        return this->center;
    }
    void OrganismPosition::setHead(CvPoint2D32f* head){
        CvPoint2D32f newhead=cvPoint2D32f(head->x,head->y);
        this->head=&newhead;
    }
    CvPoint2D32f* OrganismPosition::getHead(){
        return this->head;
    }
    void OrganismPosition::setQueue(CvPoint2D32f* queue){
        CvPoint2D32f newqueue=cvPoint2D32f(queue->x,queue->y);
        this->queue=&newqueue;
    }
    CvPoint2D32f* OrganismPosition::getQueue(){
        return this->queue;
    }
    void OrganismPosition::setSkel(CvPoint2D32f* skel1,
                 CvPoint2D32f* skel2,
                 CvPoint2D32f* skel3,
                 CvPoint2D32f* skel4){
        CvPoint2D32f newskel1=cvPoint2D32f(skel1->x,skel1->y);
        this->skel1=&newskel1;
        CvPoint2D32f newskel2=cvPoint2D32f(skel2->x,skel2->y);
        this->skel2=&newskel2;
        CvPoint2D32f newskel3=cvPoint2D32f(skel3->x,skel3->y);
        this->skel3=&newskel3;
        CvPoint2D32f newskel4=cvPoint2D32f(skel4->x,skel4->y);
        this->skel4=&newskel4;
    }
    void OrganismPosition::getSkel(CvPoint2D32f* skel1,
                CvPoint2D32f* skel2,
                CvPoint2D32f* skel3,
                CvPoint2D32f* skel4){
                skel1=this->skel1;
                skel2=this->skel2;
                skel3=this->skel3;
                skel4=this->skel4;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several mistakes. First, lets address the `pos->center` problem.

```
void OrganismPosition::setCenter(CvPoint2D32f* center){
    CvPoint2D32f newcenter=cvPoint2D32f(center->x,center->y);
    // you've created a local 2f object that resides on the stack. 
    //this will be destroyed when the function returns.
    this->center=&newcenter;
    // what you're left with is a stack pointer to garbage data.
}
```

What you want is to allocate memory on the heap.

```
void OrganismPosition::setCenter(const CvPoint2D32f* center){
    if (center)
        delete center; // free memory that you used up before.
    this->center= new cvPoint2D32f(center->x,center->y);
}
```

Now, why go through all this pointer headache in the first place? Just use `CvPoint2D32f` members in your `OrganismPosition` class. Don't create pointers unless you absolutely need to.

Comment: Thanks work now! I use this code for precision:

    if (this->center)
        delete this->center;
    this->center= new CvPoint2D32f;
    this->center->x=ctr->x;
    this->center->y=ctr->y;
Can you explain more why is better use no pointer in memeber class?

Comment: Simply because you need to add all this extra code when you use pointers. You need to do it in every setter, your copy constructor and assignment operator. Failing to do so correctly can lead to garbage data, memory leaks and simply makes code ugly.

Comment: you don't need to say `this->center` btw within a member function. `center` will do.